# Excel VBA - Selecting Items in a list and pasting into specific cell then selecting the next item

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of about 400 company codes in Column S that I would like Excel to select the first company code in Cell S2, paste it into a cell (E3) where I will then run an already created macro to find the company's parent.

Then I'd like Excel to go back to my list of company codes and pick the next one in the list (Cell S3) and paste it into the same cell and run the macro to look up parent company again. I'd like it to stop once there are no longer any cells with company codes left.

I know this is probably a very simple piece of code but I've had no luck so far and can't find any questions similar.

Here's the code I was trying but with no success. I had found another piece of code on here that was to find a blank cell so I thought I'd blank out the first cell in S1 and have it then move one cell down and grab the first code, cut and paste it, then keep repeating.

```
Sub TEST1()

For Each Cell In Range("Entities").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

Sheets("Input").Range("E3") = Cell.Value

Calculate

Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: I do not understand what you are attempting. Why have a macro that gets its input from cell E3?  Why not make the input a parameter?  How doe the macro return the parent company?

Answer (score 0):

Loops are very common in any kind of programming language. In VBA, there are several options to choose from. If you are sure the list holds no empty cells, I would probably use a While loop, so something like:

```
Option Explicit

Sub jzz()
Dim i As Long

i = 1 'first row of data

Do While Cells(i, 1) <> vbNullString
    'do something with this cell
    i = i + 1 'increment variable i
Loop

End Sub
```

This loop will run until it finds an empty cell in the first column (A).

Comment: Thank you for the input, I've tried the code you provided but I'm getting 'With...Wend' errors currently. Also a Loop with no Do? Sorry, still a noob over here.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Forgot the 'Do' in my hurry. I edited my answer (and tested it this time). Don't apologize for being a Noob, we all started there.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I tried the code with a little tinkering of my own but it keeps stopping after the first company code. Any ideas? (I posted my updated code in my original post as an edit) Is there a way to set it to start in cell S2? I think it's pasting into E3 then looking to E4 and seeing a blank and stopping...

Comment: No, not if you don't provide more info. The given code will stop executing when cell(i,1) is empty (vbNullString). So maybe the cell is empty? Is the list of company codes continuous, or does it contain empty cells? You mention copying away of data, does that leave an empty cell? Programming is really simple, you have to tell the computer what to do. Problem is, you have to tell him (or her) EXACTLY what to do, and it will do EXACTLY that. So evaluate what is going on an what is wrong. That is called debugging. Step through your code (hitting F8) th see what is going on and where it stops.

Comment: Thanks again Jzz for your help and patience. I think I've found some code that will work for this instance. The list of company codes is continous with 274 companies. Now, I would like after each company code is copied and pasted into E3 for a new macro 'Look_Up' to run which will find the company's parent company and paste it onto a new work sheet. Could you help me figure out how I can edit my macro to run 'Look_Up' after it pastes the first company in, then copy the next company in my list to E3, run 'Look_Up' again and so on and so on.

Comment: No. Look, if you want me to make your code work, hire me on Elance. This site is to help you learn how to code and to help you figure out problems. I handed you a generic solution to a common problem. As I said, looping lists is a very common programming task. If you want to learn how to code, take it from there. Loop your cells. Make that work. Then move on to the processing. If you run into problems, you're welcome to come back here. Post your code. Don't trow the entire task that was given to you here and expect people to do it for you. As said, hire a freelancer for that.

Comment: Understood, I'll keep working on this and learning as much as I can. Thanks again for your help on this.

Comment: Good luck, and sorry if I sounded rude. Again, you're welcome here if you run into trouble!

Comment: No problem, you got me off to a great start. I think what's tripping me up is I have 10 companies in column S and I need to enter them one by one into cell E3 - no need to remove the companies once copied over. I think the code you kindly provided is copying the first company correctly, pasting into cell E3, but then looking to cell E4, which is blank, and stopping. I guess I'm unclear on how I can make sure the macro continues to copy from column S. Will keep troubleshooting and researching online.